# ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound, no matter what column name I choose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

For my classes

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.inheritance_column = :user_type
  scope :customers, -> { where(user_type: '1') }
  scope :freight_forwarders, -> { where(user_type: '2') }
end

class FreightForwarder < User

  has_many :quotes, foreign_key: "ff_id"

end

class Customer < User

  has_many :quotes, foreign_key: "ff_id"

end
```

[1] I am getting the following error, when I try to call User.customers

> ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: The single-table inheritance mechanism
>   failed to locate the subclass: '1'. This error is raised because the
>   column 'user_type' is reserved for storing the class in case of
>   inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be
>   used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite
>   User.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.

[2] when I try to call Customer.all the query runs like this,

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."user_type" IN (0)
```

I am not able to understand why it is '0' it should be '1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full STI class name is stored in the column `user_type` and not a `'0'` or a `'1'`. Check the [`find_sti_class` class method.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Inheritance/ClassMethods/find_sti_class)

Here the method is trying to find a class with the name `1`

> The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass:
>   '1'.

Change your scopes to

```
  scope :customers, -> { where(user_type: 'Customer') }
  scope :freight_forwarders, -> { where(user_type: 'FreightForwarder') }
```

As for the `Customer.all` query. I do not know how it generates this query but maybe you have overridden something when you defined those scopes.